# Javascript gives invalid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs, jquerydatetimepicker

I am getting a server date (including timezone) from an API. I want to convert it to date object.

When I do this

```
var demo2 = new Date("THU JAN 19 15:37:56 PST 2017"); //It works!

var demo = new Date("FRI JAN 20 07:50:07 SGT 2017"); //Invalid date
```

Why? If it's a SGT then it doesn't work but it works for PST

I'm trying to pass this date to dateTimePicker

```
    $datetimepicker.datetimepicker({
        minDate: new Date(this.serverTime),
        defaultDate: new Date(this.serverTime),
    });
```

How can I solve this problem using Date / MomentJS?

Comment: You don't have a time zone.  You have a few letters that might refer to an abbreviation of one of several time partial time zones.  If your string from your server is indeed like that - you must go back to your server and emit valid output, preferably in ISO8601 format.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not ever parse time zone abbreviations.  They are inconsistent at best, and often ambiguous.

For example, should `CST` mean...

- Central Standard Time (UTC-6)
- Cuba Standard Time (UTC-5)
- China Standard Time (UTC+8)

Do I need to say more?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MomentJS the constructor suggest you can do something like this.
`(Date String, Date Format, TimeZone)`

You can find the timezone strings here: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

In your case you are looking for Singapore which is: `Asia/Singapore`

Simple example:

```
var date = moment.tz("Jay 20th 2017 8PM", "MMM Do YYYY hA", "Asia/Singapore");
```

Here is a link to the constructor docs: http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using this format:

```
new Date('1/20/2017 7:50:07 AM CST');
```

CST is the same time zone than SGT

Comment: Most browsers will interpret `CST` as Central standard time in the US, not as China Standard Time.  Just don't.